# SPARQL QUERY given nothing

Tags: sparql

I have two graph named as `<http://localhost:5822/fub>` & `<http://localhost:5822/fub_byrn>`.
Both graph contain MetaphoneCode.
I wanted to get result for Metaphone that have same  MetaphoneCode appear in both Graph.
After i executing this query i am no geting result.
Need help and suggestion.

```
SELECT ?MetaPhone 
WHERE
{
  GRAPH <http://localhost:5822/fub>
  { 
    GRAPH ?g {}
    { ?s <http://localhost:2020/vocab/dbo_UniData_MetaPhoneCode> ?MetaPhone . }
  }
  GRAPH <http://localhost:5822/fub_byrn> 
  {
    GRAPH ?g {}
    { ?s <http://localhost:2020/vocab/dbo_FUB_Bayern_MetaPhoneCode> ?MetaPhone . }
  }
}
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: It will be hard to answer this without seeing some of your data.  Can you run a less restrictive query (e.g., just select some triples from both graphs) so that we can see what's in each graph?

Comment: Duplicated at http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/23825/sparql-two-graph-match

Answer (score 0):

When formatted in a more readable way, your query is:

```
select ?MetaPhone where {
  Graph <http://localhost:5822/fub> {
    Graph ?g {
    }
    {
      ?s <http://localhost:2020/vocab/dbo_UniData_MetaPhoneCode> ?MetaPhone;
    }
  }

  Graph <http://localhost:5822/fub_byrn> {
    Graph ?g {
    }
    {
      ?s <http://localhost:2020/vocab/dbo_FUB_Bayern_MetaPhoneCode> ?MetaPhone;
    }
  }
}
LIMIT 100
```

There are at least two issues:

1. Your pattern `graph ?g {}` won't do anything except to bind `?g` to each graph in the dataset.  It's not clear that that should negatively affect anything, but it's hard to see why it would be useful.
2. You're using a different property for `MetaPhoneCode` in the `fub` graph and the `fub_byrn` graphs.  In `fub` it's

   ```
   <http://localhost:2020/vocab/dbo_UniData_MetaPhoneCode>
   ```

   while in `fub_byrn` it's

   ```
   <http://localhost:2020/vocab/dbo_FUB_Bayern_MetaPhoneCode>
   ```

   Are these supposed to be the same?

Comment: Actually Both have different property ,as Bothr graphe have several Title which has different MetaphoneCode.I want to check which MetaphoneCode are same .

Comment: @asherbaig Well, if these properties are different, is it possible that the URIs for the phones (that have codes) are different, too?  Perhaps you should query for `?s1 <...UniData_MetaPhoneCode> ?code` and `?s2 <...Bayern_MetaPhoneCode> ?code`, and `select ?s1 ?s2 ?code`.  Then you'd see all pairs of phones that have the same code.  This is a less restrictive query, and has potentially more results, so it's more likely that you'll get _something_ back.

Comment: I have generate some Metaphonecode on both graph which are same.I just want to display them.May be you are not understanding my issue.I am not sure.

Comment: The query looks good (aside from the `graph ?g {}` empty patterns which don't seem like they will do anything).  If your data actually has `<x> <...UniData_MetaPhoneCode> <y>` in `<...fub>` and `<x> <...Bayern_MetaPhoneCode> <y>` in `<fub_byrn>`, then I think your query should produce `<y>`.  Since we haven't seen any of your data, though, we can't tell whether the problem is with the query or with the data.